Сортировка символа "№" PostgreSQL
Написал collation для сортировки в PostgreSQL:
CREATE COLLATION test (provider = icu, locale = 'ru-RU-u-kn-true-kr-cyrl-latn')
Столкнулся с проблемой, что символ "№"(numeric sign) сортируется как "no" и соответственно оказывается среди букв, подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть его в знаки.
 Версия 15.4

Ну попробуйте добавить rules.
